# wifi - WiFi sometimes does not work

Tags: pi-3, wifi, power-supply, kernel

When I powered the Raspberry Pi 3B on (I use Gentoo), WiFi was working. After reboot, it stopped working, both `ip link list` and `ifconfig` commands do not list it (they do if WiFi is working).

I am experimenting a bit, after some reboots it was working, sometimes not.

I think it could be caused by power supply that not enough (it is only 2A). When I was using Raspbian, WiFi was working without problems with the same supply.

I tried to reboot (`shutdown -r now`) 6 times, 5 times it was OK.
When I tusrned it off (`shutdown -h now`) and reconnected supply 6 times, it was OK only 2 times.

---

What can cause this problem?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You sound like you have a promising path to test - replacing the power supply. Though you should check the voltage (carefully). It could also be the usb cable.

Comment: @NomadMaker I tried also 3A supply, it was still the same.

Comment: I compiled WiFi driver as module. It looks it works now.

Comment: If you have found an answer, can you please make an answer to finish this question?

Comment: @Ingo I was not sure. (I am still not sure it will work "forever")

Comment: Doesn't matter ;-) You can modify or even delete your answer. It is only that others doesn't look for a solution that is already solved.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled the WiFi driver as module. It works without any problems.

<sub>I think it is because WiFi is now started when is the supply not as loaded as during early boot phases (kernel load, HW starting).</sub>